# Tab Navigation does not carry after login. React-navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Hello everyone I have the following problem.

If I put the login screen to be loaded first and login, Tab Navigation does not carry when I call the main screen. However, if I first call the component of the main screen it normally carries the Tab Navigation. Follows the app code of the app. Can anybody help me?

[Project Expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@jacksonm/react-native-exemplo-error)

```js
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

// You can import from local files
import Login from '../pages/login/Login';
import TelaCadastroUsuario from '../pages/login/TelaCadastroUsuario';
import Main from '../pages/principal/Main';

const AcessoStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AcessoStackScreen() {
  return (
    <AcessoStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <AcessoStack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
        options={{ title: 'Tela login' }}
      />
      <AcessoStack.Screen
        name="TelaCadastroUsuario"
        component={TelaCadastroUsuario}
        options={{ title: 'Tela Cadastro Usuario' }}
      />
      <AcessoStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={Main}
        options={{ title: 'Tela Principal' }}
      />
    </AcessoStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const UsuarioStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function UsuarioStackScreen() {
  return (
    <UsuarioStack.Navigator>
      <UsuarioStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={Main}
        options={{ title: 'Tela Principal' }}
      />
    </UsuarioStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AuthTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="inicio"
        component={AcessoStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Inicio',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="usuario"
        component={UsuarioStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Usuário',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="user" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

import { AuthProvider, AuthContext } from './AuthContext';
import {
  SafeAreaProvider,
  useSafeAreaInsets,
} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function Router() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.error(user);
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user ? (
          <RootStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={
              {
                // headerShown: false
              }
            }
            initialRouteName={'LoggedIn'}>
            <RootStack.Screen name="LoggedIn" component={AuthTabNavigator} />
          </RootStack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <RootStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            initialRouteName={'LoggedOut'}>
            <RootStack.Screen name="LoggedOut" component={AcessoStackScreen} />
          </RootStack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

```js
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
    
    export const AuthContext = createContext({});
    
    export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
        const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    
        const signIn = (userData) => {
            // Simulate successful login
            setUser(userData);
        };
    
        const signOut = () => {
            // Simulate logout
            setUser(null);
        };
    
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, signIn, signOut}}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    };
```

**Login Screen**

```js
    import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
    //import API from '../../../config/API';
    import {
        NativeBaseProvider,
        FormControl,
        Input,
        Stack,
        WarningOutlineIcon,
        Box,
        Center,
        Button,
        Image,
        View,
        Text,
        Icon, useToast,
    } from 'native-base';
    import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; 
    import AlertMsg from '../../components/AlertMsg';
    import {AuthContext} from '../../routes/AuthContext';
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
    export default function Login({ route }) {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        const {signIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
        const [user, setUser] = useState({
            email: 'admin@admin.com',
            password: 'admin@123',
        });
    
        const toast = useToast();
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
        const Logar = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            console.log(user);
            try {
             
                if (!user.email) {
                    console.log('logar');
                    console.log(user);
                   // setUserToken('token');
                    signIn(user);
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@usuario', JSON.stringify(user)); //armazenando em "usuario" o valor de response.data
                    navigation.navigate('Main');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                let msg = (error);
                toast.show({
                    render: () => {
                        return <AlertMsg status="error" msg={msg}/>;
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    
        return (
            <NativeBaseProvider>
                <Center flex={1} px="3" backgroundColor="#CBEDD1">
                    <Box alignItems="center">
                        <View maxWidth="130px">
                            <Image
                                maxHeight="130px"
                                source={require('../../assets/imagemLogin.jpg')}
                            />
                        </View>
    
                        <Box w="100%" maxWidth="300px">
                            <FormControl isRequired>
                                <Stack mx="4">
                                    <Box>
                                        <FormControl isInvalid>
                                            <Input
                                                type="user"
                                                placeholder="Usuário"
                                                marginTop="10px"
                                                backgroundColor="white"
                                                name="email"
                                                value={user.email}
                                                onChangeText={(value) =>
                                                    setUser({...user, email: value})
                                                }
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </Box>
    
                                    <Box>
                                        <FormControl isInvalid>
                                            <Input
                                                marginTop="10px"
                                                backgroundColor="white"
                                                type="password"
                                                name="password"
                                                value={user.password}
                                                secureTextEntry={true}
                                                onChangeText={(value) =>
                                                    setUser({...user, password: value})
                                                }
                                                placeholder="******"
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </Box>
    
                                    {/*<FormControl.HelperText> No mínimo 6 caracteres. </FormControl.HelperText>*/}
                                    <FormControl.HelperText>
                                        {' '}
                                        Problemas com login?{' '}
                                    </FormControl.HelperText>
    
                                    <Box alignItems="center">
                                        <Button
                                            marginTop="10px"
                                            backgroundColor="white"
                                            onPress={Logar}>
                                            <Text colorScheme="dark">Login</Text>
                                        </Button>
    
                                        <Button
                                            marginTop="10px"
                                            backgroundColor="white"
                                            onPress={() =>
                                                navigation.navigate('TelaCadastroUsuario', {item: ''})
                                            }>
                                            <Text colorScheme="dark">Cadastre-se</Text>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Box>
    
                                    <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                                        leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs"/>}>
                                        Atleast 6 characters are required.
                                    </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                                </Stack>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Center>
            </NativeBaseProvider>
        );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        inputFormato: {
            marginTop: '10px',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 'full',
        },
    });
```

**Main Screen**

```js
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
    import { NativeBaseProvider, Box, Button, Icon, Fab } from 'native-base';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    import { AuthContext } from '../../routes/AuthContext';
    // You can import from local files
    
    export default function Main({ navigation }) {
      const usuario = AsyncStorage.getItem('@usuario');
      const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
      return (
        <Box>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('Login');
              //alert(item.id);
            }}>
            Usuario: {user?.email}  Usuario storage: {usuario?.email}
            
          </Button>
          <Button onPress={() => console.log('hello world')}>Click Me</Button>
        </Box>
      );
    }
```